# Moving my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I need to move my top horizontal navbar all the way to the right beside my header that says "Best TV Ever" I've floated it to the right, now it has to move up to the top of the page.

How do I do this?

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qkLgqmfh/

As well as the code.

```
h1{
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: Peralta;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 150px;}

h2{
    font-family: Peralta;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

p{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 3em;
    display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
    height:130px;
}

img{
    float: left;

    margin-right: 1em;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;}



ul li {
  display: inline-block;
 float: right;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.topnav ul li a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
background-color: white;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 15px;}

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">


    <div id="masthead">
        <h1>Best TV Ever</h1>
            </div>


[insert menu toggle here]
[insert menu checkbox here]

  <div class="topnav"> 
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">50s</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">60s</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">70s</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">80s</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">90s</a></li>
    </ul>
        </div>
```

I've been staring at this computer screen for 6 hours now and feel like my mind has just given up. I'm sure it's simple... but for the life of me I cant figure it out!

Comment: Do you want [this](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/qkLgqmfh/1/) ?

Comment: No, the numbers have to literally be in the black beside the h1. I have a white background on them and they should be in a circle. (but you cant see it right now due to the white background they are already on.) so it has to look like this (in a nut shell)

Comment: Best TV Ever                              50's   60's   70's   80's   90's with "best tv ever" all the way to the left, and the nav bar all the way to the right

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have your `float: right;` on the `li` instead of on the `.topnav`. That is your main issue.

I changed that and removed a lot of cluster and this is what I got: https://jsfiddle.net/qkLgqmfh/3/

I think that is what you wanted to achieve.

**Edit:** If you want the black background on the whole width, put the `topnav` and `h1` together in a new `div` and set `background-color: black;`. And since the div only contains floated elements, it will render with 0 height and width, so you need to set `overflow: hidden;` as well (unless you want to give it a specific height).

Regarding the size of the links, you can just change the `font-size`.

Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/qkLgqmfh/5/

Comment: No, that's not right either. The float left constricts the background color of the header this way. I need the black background to be the width of the screen with the white links on top it. I figured it out, but now I'm trying to change their size. They're too small.